# How to iterate a dictionary with another dictionary list with different items in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I want to iterate my dict in multiple times

Input :
list of one

list1 :[
{
"A" : "a",
"B" : "b"
}
]

list2 : [
{
"something" : "",
"something" : ""
},
{
"something" : "",
"something" : ""
},
{
"something" : "",
"something" : ""
}
]

Here list1 should update list2 items with list1 key values

I tried this but it prints only one dictionary

for list2 in list1:
json.dump(data, file, indent=4)

Expected output :
list 1 = [
{
"A" : "a",
"B" : "b"
},
{
"A" : "a",
"B" : "b"
},
{
"A" : "a",
"B" : "b"
}
]

Comment: i don't get the point of `list2`. and your code is not valid

Comment: list 1 will get update list 2 index of times

Comment: You seem to be asking the same question in several slightly different ways on SO. Why not just use `list1 = [list1[0] for i in range(3)]` as the content of list2 is both irrelevant and not correct Python (repeated keys are not accepted).

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension:

```
list1 = [{"A": "a", "B": "b"}]
list2 = [{
    "something": "",
    "something": ""
}, {
    "something": "",
    "something": ""
}, {
    "something": "",
    "something": ""
}]

list3 = [list1 for item in list2] # or [list1[0] for item in list2]
print(list3)
```

Out:

```
[[{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b'}], [{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b'}], [{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b'}]]
```

Comment: I'm getting run time error : RuntimeWarning: assigning None to unbound local 'item